# How to setup jakarta.ws.rs in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jersey

I have used Jakarta rs-ws with Dropwizard for a while now and it's been rather seamless. I want to set up the same for Springboot and I have been encountering an error. I have read up people with similar issues on Stackoverflow and I have tried to follow suit but it's not working on my end.

This is the config I did based on some articles I read online.

This is what my Apllication class looks like

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CrosspointApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedOriginPattern("/**");
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList(
                HttpMethod.GET.name(),
                HttpMethod.HEAD.name(),
                HttpMethod.POST.name(),
                HttpMethod.PUT.name(),
                HttpMethod.DELETE.name()));
        corsConfiguration.setMaxAge(1800L);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration); // you restrict your path here
        return source;
    }

    @Configuration
    class JerseyConfiguration {
        @Bean
        AuthController auth(AuthService authService, RefreshTokenService refreshTokenService) {
            return new AuthController(authService, refreshTokenService);
        }

        @Bean
        ResourceConfig resourceConfig(AuthController auth) {
            ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
            resourceConfig.register(auth);
            return resourceConfig;
        }


    }
```

Here is my controller

```
@Api
@Path("/api/v1/auth")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class AuthController {
    private final AuthService auth;
    private final RefreshTokenService tokenService;


    @Path("/register")
    @POST
    @PermitAll
    public Response signUp(@Valid RegisterDto register) throws CrossPointException{
        return Response.ok(auth.signup(register)).build();
    }
```

I added  this line of code to my application.properties

```
context-path=/auth
```

My POM file where the issue might be coming from.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
<!--        <version>3.1.0-M8</version>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
       </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.33</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Once I hit the endpoint above on Postman, I get this error. Here is the complete stack trace

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerExecutorProvidersConfigurator.registerExecutors(Lorg/glassfish/jersey/internal/inject/InjectionManager;Lorg/glassfish/jersey/model/internal/ComponentBag;Lorg/glassfish/jersey/spi/ExecutorServiceProvider;Lorg/glassfish/jersey/spi/ScheduledExecutorServiceProvider;)V
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerExecutorProvidersConfigurator.init(ServerExecutorProvidersConfigurator.java:62) ~[jersey-server-2.33.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:345) ~[jersey-server-2.33.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$1(ApplicationHandler.java:293) ~[jersey-server-2.33.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292) ~[jersey-common-2.35.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274) ~[jersey-common-2.35.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:232) ~[jersey-common-2.35.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:292) ~[jersey-server-2.33.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:259) ~[jersey-server-2.33.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.35.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:154) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.35.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:347) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.35.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1164) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:804) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:128) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [na:1.8.0_322]

2022-10-26 12:17:32.556 ERROR 20535 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[.g.j.s.ResourceConfig]  : Allocate exception for servlet [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig]

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerExecutorProvidersConfigurator.registerExecutors(Lorg/glassfish/jersey/internal/inject/InjectionManager;Lorg/glassfish/jersey/model/internal/ComponentBag;Lorg/glassfish/jersey/spi/ExecutorServiceProvider;Lorg/glassfish/jersey/spi/ScheduledExecutorServiceProvider;)V
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerExecutorProvidersConfigurator.init(ServerExecutorProvidersConfigurator.java:62) ~[jersey-server-2.33.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:345) ~[jersey-server-2.33.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$1(ApplicationHandler.java:293) ~[jersey-server-2.33.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292) ~[jersey-common-2.35.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274) ~[jersey-common-2.35.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:232) ~[jersey-common-2.35.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:292) ~[jersey-server-2.33.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:259) ~[jersey-server-2.33.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.35.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:154) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.35.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:347) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.35.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:804) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:128) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [na:1.8.0_322]

2022-10-26 12:17:32.561 ERROR 20535 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Servlet.init() for servlet [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig] threw exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resource configuration is not modifiable in this context.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$ImmutableState.register(ResourceConfig.java:248) ~[jersey-server-2.33.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$ImmutableState.register(ResourceConfig.java:195) ~[jersey-server-2.33.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.register(ResourceConfig.java:428) ~[jersey-server-2.33.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:306) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.35.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:154) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.35.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:347) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.35.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1164) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:804) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:687) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:385) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:403) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:249) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:344) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [na:1.8.0_322]

2022-10-26 12:17:32.562 ERROR 20535 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[.g.j.s.ResourceConfig]  : Allocate exception for servlet [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resource configuration is not modifiable in this context.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$ImmutableState.register(ResourceConfig.java:248) ~[jersey-server-2.33.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$ImmutableState.register(ResourceConfig.java:195) ~[jersey-server-2.33.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.register(ResourceConfig.java:428) ~[jersey-server-2.33.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:306) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.35.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:154) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.35.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:347) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.35.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:804) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:687) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:385) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:403) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:249) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:344) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [na:1.8.0_322]

2022-10-26 12:17:32.562 ERROR 20535 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig] threw exception
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1181) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:804) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:687) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:385) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:403) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:249) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:344) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [na:1.8.0_322]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resource configuration is not modifiable in this context.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$ImmutableState.register(ResourceConfig.java:248) ~[jersey-server-2.33.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$ImmutableState.register(ResourceConfig.java:195) ~[jersey-server-2.33.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.register(ResourceConfig.java:428) ~[jersey-server-2.33.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:306) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.35.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:154) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.35.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:347) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.35.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Comment: What is your application server in which your application is run?

Comment: By default, Springboot uses Tomcat I guess

Comment: You could not run Jakarta on tomcat

Comment: Just doing a quick search, it looks like Spring Boot 3 uses Jakarta. You shouldn't have to add any base Jersey  dependencies yourself is you use the starter. And if you do, make sure they are 3.x dependencies.

Comment: I am using Spring 2.6.5. Let me see if upgrading solves the problem. Most importantly I am not sure if my ResourceConfiguration is right

Comment: @rezaramezanimatin why so please? Can you provide an alternative?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I think the latest Springboot is 2.7.5 it's only if I am missing anything.

Comment: @CuriousCat Havent used Spring Boot in a while. Just based on first search result of "Spring Boot with Jakarta" :) Guess it's not right